# Passing create inside of method rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In controller you can pass create by the code below:

```
expect {
          post :create, params: {question: valid_attributes}, session: valid_session
        }.to change(Question, :count).by(1)
```

What if the create is inside of a method? I have a method that behaves find or create. And it will return the `id`.

```
def my_method(id='')
  if id.blank?
    question = Question.create(content: "The content.")
  else
    question = Question.find(id)
  end

  question.id
end
```

I do the Rspec like this:

```
it "should create for non existence of id" do
  expect(my_method).to have(1).record
end

it "should return object base on id" do
  expect(assigns(:question)).to eq(question)
end
```

But it gives me this error:

```
 NoMethodError:
       undefined method `have' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ClassNameHere:0x00000008543a50>
```

Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Where is this `my_method` placed? and where do you call it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic. Instead of:

```
expect(my_method).to have(1).record
```

you should explicitly call the method (I assume it’s a class method of `Question`) and then check `Question` for having records. Methods do not have records for obvious reason:

```
Question.my_method
expect(Question).to have(1).record
```